# Angular Material - Know exactly which tab was selected

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

So I might have missed something obvious in the docs, but I'm simply looking for an easy way to find which tab has been selected in the following scenario:

### View

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngIf="true" label="Label1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="false" label="Label2">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="true" label="Label3">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Obviously, the conditions are dynamic in my actual code. This is just for the sample.

### Script

```
onTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
  // ?
}
```

### Issue

In the above script, `event.index` will return 0 if I click the first tab, and **1 if I click the third tab**, because the second one isn't displayed due to `*ngIf`.

This does make sense to me, however it's making it really hard to know **which tab was actually clicked** depending on which ones were displayed to begin with.

I could either:

- test again for every tab condition within `onTabChange` to figure out which index corresponds to which tab,
- (probably) bind a `ViewChild(ren)` reference to something and retrieve data (such as `data-` attributes) through their native DOM elements.

Both these options seem super overkill though.

### Question

In the above code, what would be the appropriate way to know that, say, the tab labelled `Label3` was clicked, without testing for the label itself (which would obviously be horrendous)?

[Simple Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uajlrc?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html) if that can help.

Comment: try hiding your tab instead of removing it from DOM, i.e try using `[hidden] = "true"` instead of `*ngIf`

Comment: @SarthakAggarwal Nice suggestion and I actually tried that as well (on `<mat-tab>`), but the tab still shows anyway as you can try on the StackBlitz. I'll try to find specific related issues.

Comment: I ran into this as well a while back, it is unfortunate that you have to rely on the tab's index. I have (just now) created a [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13921). The feature request is to allow the dev. to set a unique name per tab which can then be read back in the event on the `MatTab` instance. Please up-vote it (thumbs-up it) and let me know if I missed anything. Hopefully they will address it some point soon.

Comment: @Igor Thanks, awesome. I'll link this SO post to it in case it can provide some additional insight. I didn't read your entire post because I gotta run but I'll let you know if I find anything important missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually answering myself twice because I think this solution is interesting as well, and probably closest (yet) to what I'm looking for:

### View

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngIf="true" label="tab1">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>Label 1</ng-template>
    Content 1
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="false" label="tab2">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>Label 2</ng-template>
    Content 2
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="true" label="tab3">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>Label 3</ng-template>
    Content 3
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

### Script

```
onTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
  const tabName = event.tab.textLabel;
  // ...
}
```

Basically, this uses the other way to add a (title) text label to the tab, using `<ng-template>`, which seems to take precedence over the `label` attribute.

This latter attribute can therefore be used to store the "programmatic" name of the tab (as opposed to its public text) and is easily retrieved on script side.

Answer (score 4):

Use `aria-labelledby` attribute to identify tab without resorting to human-readable text labels.

```
<mat-tab aria-labelledby="tab-x">
    <span *matTabLabel id="tab-x" i18n>Tab X</span>
</mat-tab>
```

In the code:

```
onTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    const tabId = event.tab.ariaLabelledby;
    if (tabId === 'tab-x') { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (it's an old question and I'm not doing much Angular right now so I'll need some time to get back to it, but when I do I'll make sure to mark your answer as accepted if it seems like the better solution).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what I was looking for, but here's the best solution I've found in the meantime:

### View

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab *ngIf="true" data-name="tab1" label="Label1">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="false" data-name="tab2" label="Label2">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab *ngIf="true" data-name="tab3" label="Label3">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

### Script

```
onTabChange(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
  const tabName = event.tab.content.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.dataset.name;
  // ...
}
```

Looks a bit hackish (and very verbose), but does the job.

PS: thanks to @GreenMonkeyBoy on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/angular/material2) for helping in finding this!